# jackson mapper with special character é issue

Tags: java, json, angularjs, jackson

Hi i have  web page which submits a charecter say like this `José Luis Calleja Garcia`

But in the server its get converted to `JosÃ© Luis Calleja Garcia`.

I dont know what i am doing wrong. what configuration i should set to get it as `José Luis Calleja Garcia`.

I am submitting the multipart request like this in angular service

```
var config = {
    method: "POST",
    url: 'some url',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': false },
    transformRequest: function (data) {
        var formData = new FormData();  
        formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.getFormDefinition()));
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                formData.append(data.files[i].name, data.files[i]);
            }
            return formData;
        },
    data:requestModel   
};
```

And my server side object mapper configuration  is like this

```
public class CustomViewObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{

    public CustomViewObjectMapper() {
        super();

        this.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector());
        this.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        this.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);   
    }
}
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What encoding are you using? Have you tried `uft-8`?

Comment: where? jackson documentation says, when deserializing the jason it detects automatically

Comment: Use "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" in your angular request

Comment: @user1224036 Jackson detects encoding from valid possibilities -- only valid encodings for JSON are UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. But your web server (or client) can accidentally use some non-supported encoding, such ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1); in which case there is nothing parser can do -- Latin-1 is unfortunately not automatically detectable from UTF-8. So in most cases problems are with producer that use a non-Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unicode code point for é is U+00E9, which becomes 0xC3 0xA9 in UTF-8. Now, in ISO-8859-1, 0xC3 is Ã, and 0xA9 is ©. So, it seems that you are sending the data in UTF-8, but interpreting it as ISO-8859-1.

Or, you could try adding a content type header:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

to make sure the server interprets it correctly.